# How to implement OCaml function of type (string*int) list -> (string * int list) list where the output list is a tally of the items in the input

Tags: list, ocaml, higher-order-functions

The question I have is how might I transform a list of a string and integer pair to a list of string and int list pairs.

For example, if I have the list `[("hello",1) ; ("hi", 1) ; ("hello", 1) ; ("hi", 1) ; ("hey",1 )]` then I should get back `[("hello",[1;1]) ; ("hi", [1;1]) ; ("hey",[1])]` where basically from a previous function I wrote that creates string * int pairs in a list, I want to group every string that's the same into a pair that has a list of ones of a length = to how many times that exact string appeared in a pair from the input list. Sorry if my wording is confusing but I am quite lost on this function. Below is the code I have written so far:

```
let transform5 (lst: (string *int) list) : (string *int list) list = 
                match lst with
                   | (hd,n)::(tl,n) -> let x,[o] = List.fold_left (fun (x,[o]) y -> if y = x then x,[o]@[1] else 
(x,[o])::y,[o]) (hd,[o]) tl in (x,[1])::(tl,[1])
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this homework or can you use a `Map`? See this [tutorial](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/map.html)

Comment: @DanRobertson Looks like it is a homework question, and a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794793/write-an-ocaml-function-that-takes-a-stringint-list-string-int-list-li (which I missed before). The earlier question specifies the solution should be implemented in terms of a fold.

Comment: I can use map, honestly not sure why I did not think of that before.

Answer (score 0):

#### General advice on how to improve understanding of core concepts:

The code suggests you could use more practice with destructuring and manipulating lists. I recommend reading the chapter on [Lists and Patterns](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/lists-and-patterns.html) in *Real World Ocaml* and spending some time working through the first 20 or so [99 OCaml Problems](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html).

#### Some pointers on the code you've written so far:

I have reorganized your code into a strictly equivalent function, with some annotations indicating problem areas:

```ml
let transform5 : (string * int) list -> (string * int list) list =
  fun lst ->
  let f (x, [o]) y =
    if y = x then          (* The two branches of this conditional are values of different types *)
      (x, [o] @ [1])       (* : ('a * int list) *)
    else
      (x, [o]) :: (y, [o]) (* : ('a * int list) list *)
  in
  match lst with
  | (hd, n) :: (tl, n) ->                      (* This will only match a list with two tuples *)
    let x, [o] = List.fold_left f (hd, [o]) tl (* [o] can only match a singleton list *)
    in (x, [1]) :: (tl, [1])                   (* Doesn't use the value of o, so that info is lost*)
   (* case analysis in match expressions should be exhaustive, but this omits
      matches for, [], [_], and (_ :: _ :: _) *)
```

If you load your code in `utop` or compile it in a file, you should get a number of warnings and type errors that help indicate problem areas. You can learn a lot by taking up each of those messages one by one and working out what they are indicating.

#### Refactoring the problem

A solution to your problem using a fold over the input list is probably the right way to go. But writing solutions that use explicit recursion and break the task down into a number of sub-problems can often help study the problem and make the underlying mechanics very clear.

In general, a function of type `'a -> 'b` can be understood as a problem:

> Given a `x : 'a`, construct a `y : 'b` where ...

Our function has type `(string * int) list -> (string * int list) list` and you
state the problem quite clearly, but I've edited a bit to fit the format:

> Given `xs : (string * int) list`, construct `ys: (string * int list) list`
>     where I want to group every string from `xs` that's the same into a pair
>     `(string * int list)` in `ys` that has a list of ones of a length = to how
>     many times that exact string appeared in a pair from `xs`.

We can break this into two sub-problems:

> Given `xs : (string * int) list`, construct `ys : (string * int) list list` where each `y : (string * int) list` in `ys` is a group of the items in `xs` with the same `string`.

```ml
let rec group : (string * int) list -> (string * int) list list = function
  | [] -> []
  | x :: xs ->
    let (grouped, rest) = List.partition (fun y -> y = x) xs in
    (x :: grouped) :: group rest
```

> Given `xs : (string * int) list list`, construct `ys : (string * int list) list` where for each group `(string, int) list` in `xs` we have one `(s : string, n : int list)` in `ys` where `s` is the string determining the group and `n` is a list holding all the `1`s in the group.

```ml
let rec tally : (string * int) list list -> (string * int list) list = function
  | [] -> []
  | group :: xs ->
    match group with
    | [] -> tally xs (* This case shouldn't arise, but we match it to be complete *)
    | (s, _) :: _ ->
      let ones = List.map (fun (_, one) -> one) group in
      (s, ones) :: tally xs
```

The solution to your initial problem will just be the composition of these two sub-problems:

```ml
let transform5 : (string * int) list -> (string * int list) list =
  fun xs -> (tally (group xs))
```

Hopefully this is a helpful illustration of one way to go about decomposing these kinds of problems. However, there are some obvious defects with the code I have written: it is inefficient, in that it creates an intermediate data structure and it must iterate through the first list repeatedly to form its groups, before finally tallying up the results. It also resorts to explicit recursion, whereas it would be preferable to use higher order functions to take care of iterating over the lists for us (as you tried in your example). Trying to fix these defects might be instructive.

#### Reconsidering our context

Is the problem you've posed in this SO question the best sub-problem from the overall task you are pursuing? Here are two questions have occurred to me:

Why, do you have a `(string * int) list` where the value of `int` is always `1` in the first place? Does this actually carry any more information than a `string list`?

In general, we can represent any `n : int` by a `int list` which contains only `1`s and has `length = n`. By why not just use n here?

Comment: is there any way to do this without using recursive functions?

Comment: Yes! But your question did not indicate this limitation, so it was not addressed in my answer :) To write a fold to solve the problem, you need to think of what value you want to get out at the end, and how to incrementally construct that value given each element of the list in succession. Define a function that performs this incremental update, and you have your fold recipe.